# SQL : How to use count, sum and max function at the same sql command for MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'm so beginner at SQL. I'm only can do all this separately however i was confused when i have to do all these at the same SQL command. So could you please kindly help me on this..

I have 3 tables tbl_user, tbl_sActivity, tbl_client

```
tbl_user
    user_id | first_name | last_name |
    1       |  name1     |  last1    |
    21      |  name2     |  last2    |
    22      |  name3     |  last3    |

tbl_sActivity
user_id | client_id | act_status | act_date |
 1      |    7      |    cold    | 19/7/12  |
 1      |    7      |   dealed   | 30/7/12  |
 22     |    5      |    cold    | 7/8/12   |
 1      |    6      |    cold    | 16/7/12  |
 1      |    6      |    warm    | 18/7/12  |
 1      |    6      |     hot    | 25/7/12  |
 1      |    6      |   dealed   | 7/8/12   |
 1      |    8      |    warm    | 1/8/12   |
 1      |    8      |   dealed   | 12/8/12  |
 21     |    4      |    warm    | 8/8/12   |
 21     |    4      |   dealed   | 10/8/12  |

tbl_client
client_id | client_price |
4         |     400      |
5         |     500      |
6         |     600      |
7         |     700      |
8         |     800      |
```

I want the output looks like this

```
user_id |Count_Client_id |Sum_client_price | Max_act_date|
1       |     3          |     2100        |   12/8/12   |
21      |     1          |      400        |   10/8/12   |
22      |     1          |      500        |    7/8/12   |
```

thank you very much
below is my attempt...

```
SELECT tbl_user.user_id, Count(tbl_client.client_id) AS count_client, 
       Sum(tbl_client.client_price) AS SumOfclient_price, tbl_user.first_name,
       tbl_user.last_name, Max(tbl_sActivity.act_date) AS MaxOfact_date
FROM   (tbl_client INNER JOIN tbl_sActivity ON 
       (tbl_client.client_id=tbl_sActivity.client_id) AND 
       (tbl_sActivity.client_id=tbl_client.client_id)) INNER JOIN tbl_user ON
        tbl_sActivity.user_id=tbl_user.user_id
GROUP BY tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.first_name, tbl_user.last_name;
```

And this is the count(distinct client_id) that return the correct output

```
SELECT tmp.user_id, Count(*) AS count_distinct_clients
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, client_id FROM tbl_sActivity)  AS tmp
GROUP BY tmp.user_id;
```

Comment: Can you post the query you tried? Would help us know where to begin helping you with finding the right solution.

Comment: +1, i was abt to write that query, but would like to see what has been done. Could be homework? ;)

Comment: are you sure your result is true.?

Comment: sorry i've tried to make it more easy to read but couldn't do it.. Here's is my attempt..<br>SELECT tbl_user.user_id, Count(tbl_client.client_id) AS count_client, Sum(tbl_client.client_price) AS SumOfclient_price, tbl_user.first_name, tbl_user.last_name, Max(tbl_sActivity.act_date) AS MaxOfact_date
FROM (tbl_client INNER JOIN tbl_sActivity ON (tbl_client.client_id=tbl_sActivity.client_id) AND (tbl_sActivity.client_id=tbl_client.client_id)) INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_sActivity.user_id=tbl_user.user_id
GROUP BY tbl_user.user_id, tbl_user.first_name, tbl_user.last_name;

Comment: @Abhinav this is not my homework.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried and tested Access 2003:

```
SELECT U.user_id, Count(A.act_status) AS Count_Client_id, Sum(C.client_price) AS
Sum_client_price, Max(A.act_date) AS Max_act_date
FROM (tbl_user AS U INNER JOIN tbl_sActivity AS A ON U.user_id = A.user_id) INNER JOIN 
tbl_client AS C ON A.client_id = C.client_id
GROUP BY U.user_id
```

Updated to produce output as per example:

```
SELECT U.user_id, Count(A.client_id) AS CountOfclient_id, Sum(A.client_price) AS
SumOfclient_price, S.Max_act_date
FROM (tbl_user AS U INNER JOIN [SELECT DISTINCT tbl_SActivity.client_id, 
tbl_SActivity.user_id, tbl_client.client_price
FROM tbl_SActivity INNER JOIN tbl_client ON tbl_SActivity.client_id = 
tbl_client.client_id]. AS A ON U.user_id = A.user_id) INNER JOIN [SELECT MAX(act_date) AS Max_act_date, user_id FROM tbl_sActivity GROUP by user_id]. AS S ON U.user_id = S.user_id
GROUP BY U.user_id, S.Max_act_date
```

Comment: This is the only MS Access SQL answer that I can see.

Comment: um.. but the result is still not correct. You see that Sql should count only unique client_id which user_id(1) should return only 3 client_id(s) and for Sum(client_price), it should return 2100 for user_id(1). only  MAX_act_date that returns correct output. @Mat Donnan

Comment: @Alxan Please see my updated SQL, it now matches the output shown in the question

Comment: ok...sorry i may not explain clearly.. here's what i want... I need to know how many client_id that belong to each user_id (This one i think we can use Count(client_id). At the same time i'm also want to know sum of client_price that each user_id earn Sum(client_price). At Last the latest date that this user_id had been working Max(act_date)..- thank you very much

Comment: @Alxan That's ok, the second SQL I have posted should provide the results your example provides, please confirm this is ok or if it needs something else?

Comment: yess! this is the output that i want. Thank you so much.!! :)

Answer (score -2):

try this query. i tested:

```
SELECT  a.user_id ,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.client_ID) Count_Client_id,
    SUM( DISTINCT c.client_Price) Sum_client_price,
    MAX(b.act_date) Max_act_date
FROM    tbl_user a
        INNER JOIN tbl_sActivity b
            on a.user_id = b.user_id
        INNER JOIN tbl_client c
            on b.client_ID = c.client_ID
GROUP BY a.user_ID
```

enjoy.

Comment: The tags say MS Access. SQL is a generic tag and does not mean MS SQL. Your query will not run in the database that the OP is using.